# SQLAlchemy Object is already attached to session, then DetachedInstanceError on refresh, still adds to database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having some trouble with making a Many-to-Many relationship in Flask using SQLAlchemy. I have my two models, and the relationship table. When I create a `Group` object, I want that group to have the user who creates the group as a member, and the user should have the group being created as a group.

However, when I submit the form to create the group, I get a `InvalidRequestError`, saying `Object '<User at 0x7f85ad606a50>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')`

Then, if I refresh the page, resubmitting the form, it successfully creates the group and database relationship. However, it shows a `DetachedInstanceError`, saying that `Parent instance <User at 0x7f85ad606a50> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'groups' cannot proceed`. That error shows until I restart the server.

Relevant code:

db:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Models:

```
groups = db.Table('user_groups',
    db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('groups.id')),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    groups = db.relationship('Group', secondary=groups,
        backref=db.backref('members', lazy='dynamic'))


class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Attempting to add the group to the database:

```
g = Group()
db.session.add(g)        
u = User.query.filter_by(googleID=session.get('id')).first()
g.members.append(u)
db.session.commit()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it... The issue was that I was importing the database variable (db) into my model file. Apparently that's a no-no. So I just copy/pasted it into the main file.